# Rust (warp) How to discard unauthorized requests?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

Let's say I have a function that checks if an authorization header is valid and if the authentication is correct. How do I make a warp filter that discards all requests with invalid header or false credentials?

Comment: just make it return a `Result<(), Reject>`?

Comment: Can you please include a code example of the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the authorization header using Warp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988438/how-to-check-the-authorization-header-using-warp)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a function that builds a filter that does exactly that:

```rust
/// A warp filter that checks the authorization through API tokens.
/// The header `API_TOKEN_HEADER` should be present and valid otherwise the request is rejected.
pub async fn api_token_filter(
    context: SharedContext,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = (), Error = Rejection> + Clone {
    let with_context = warp::any().map(move || context.clone());
    warp::header::header(API_TOKEN_HEADER)
        .and(with_context)
        .and_then(authorize_token)
        .and(warp::any())
        .untuple_one()
}
```

Where:
`API_TOKEN_HEADER` is the header you want to check.
`authorize_token` is a function with signature

```rust
async fn authorize_token(token: String, context: SharedContext) -> Result<(), Rejection>
```

That actually computes the authentication.

Comment: Where is the `SharedContext` type coming from? That's application specific, not warp code yes?

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi, yes, this came from a functional piece of code. But the shared context is just an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` of some struct.